# Why does my PC always complain about the memory slots on my printer?

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-shares

I've got Windows 10 Pro. I've also got an Epson WF-3540 printer with some slots for memory cards. For some reason I've got 2 of those slots mapped on my PC. My wife's Windows 10 Home PC, doesn't. My PC complains every time I log in that it cannot reach those drive locations on the Epson.

Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look: [EPSON: How to configure the memory card slot for access across the network](https://www.epson.eu/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/faq//2830)

> To share the memory card slot on a network, set **File Sharing Setup** to
>   **Enable** on the printer's control panel.

If you go through this article, you'll hopefully find the desired solution.

Comment: I get to the point of going into the File Sharing Setup. One there I have 2 options. USB and Wi-Fi/Network. There's no Enable. I click on Wi-Fi Network and all it does is goes back to the previous menu. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If this article don't help, try to ask a vendor.